# Spring boot 2 configure reactive mongo db repository WITHOUT EmbeddedMongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a Spring Boot 2 project with Mongo DB but I the problem I am facing is that it keeps spinning up an embedded mongo DB even though I have configured to use external mongo

logs

```
2018-11-27 18:56:05.725  INFO 73687 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
2018-11-27 18:56:05.742  INFO 73687 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2018-11-27T18:56:05.741+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=73690 port=50303 dbpath=/var/folders/pf/qp_pv2xn7xb7ysnltp6tc97cstys_v/T/embedmongo-db-c2738896-198f-4934-87c4-3bd773508af7 64-bit host=MBP15-N5AXG8WP
2018-11-27 18:56:05.742  INFO 73687 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2018-11-27T18:56:05.741+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.5.5
2018-11-27 18:56:05.742  INFO 73687 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2018-11-27T18:56:05.741+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 98515c812b6fa893613f063dae568ff8319cbfbd
2018-11-27 18:56:05.742  INFO 73687 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2018-11-27T18:56:05.741+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
```

Config

```
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class MongoReactiveApplication  {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
    }

}
```

yaml
`spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest`

How should I change configuration to use external mongo?

Comment: yaml is wrong, you have set it up as properties

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar even if you use the property form it should still be read into the environment fine; Spring Boot will fail fast on unreadable properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these beans helped me to connect to my external mongo

```
@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
private String mongoUri;

@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
}

@Bean
public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
    return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory());
}

@Bean
public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory() {
    return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(mongoClient(), "mongotest");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest
```

Comment: like i stated in the question, I have this property already there